# Implement RDKit and Postgres in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, rdkit

I started to use rdkit and try to implement in Django with postgres. So I installed rdkit in my django virtualenv with `pip install rdkit-pypi` and also installed django-rdkit(https://github.com/rdkit/django-rdkit). This command: `python3 -c "from rdkit import Chem; print(Chem.MolToMolBlock(Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1CCC1')))"` works fine to me. But when I run migrate, it failed. The error is :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/rdkit.control": No such file or directory
```

It seems failed to create cartridge rdkit with postgres.
Anyone can help me find the problem and solution (better not with Conda, cause I never use it before)? Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess I have to move to Conda…

Comment: rdkit as a python package and rdkit as a PostgreSQL extension are different things.  (Although the latter might include the former, I don't know).  You have to make sure you installed the PostgreSQL-specific part of the software.

Comment: Thanks jjanes. But I don't know how to add extension to postgres in pip way. So at this moment, I just solve the problem with conda installed rdkit-postgresql and rdkit-pypi. I kept postgresql running under conda env and my django running under pipenv...And django-rdkit can provide special mol field... fingers crossed...

Answer (score 0):

OK I will answer by myself and close this question since the project is running well. I have to use conda and used conda-forge to create an rdkit extension for postgres can solve this problem.
To create Rdkit-postgres cartridge just run:

```
    conda create -n environment
    (environment) $ conda activate rdkit-postgres
    (environment) $ conda install -c conda-forge postgresql
    (environment) $ conda install -c rdkit rdkit-postgresql
```

To create django with rdkit need install django-rdkit(https://github.com/rdkit/django-rdkit).

need to mention a bit difference is that I created the extension in database manually not by django-rdkit automatically due to some permission denied in case someone comes across the same situation.